# How to make user session go on for 24 hours?

Tags: php, apache, session, web-applications

I have messed around with my apache and php.ini file and my site's users still complain about the site logging them out after a very short time or every time they close and open the same browser.

I am running Apache and PHP.

What settings should I have in order to make the users session go for 24 hours so they don't have to re-log in every time?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In php.ini, set:

```
; 24 hour session cookie
session.cookie_lifetime = 86400

; Prevent server from cleaning up session
; Some value higher than the cookie lifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime = 200000
```

Comment: Thanks, by the way, after changing the values, do I have to restart the apache server?

Comment: @Genadinik Yes you'll need to restart Apache.

Answer (score 4):

Strange. Sessions should stay for quite a long time.
Try checking your code for any accidental session_destroy()s.

If that doesn't work, then maybe try using cookies:

```
setcookie(name, value, expire);
```

So, to set a cookie variable in PHP, you would simple use

```
<?php
    setcookie("MyCookie", "MyValue", time()+60*60*24); 
?>
```

The expire value is in seconds. Using the code above, you would be able to set a cookie called "MyCookie" with the value "MyValue" and lasts for 24 hours.

To retrieve the value of this cookie, you could use

```
<?php
    print($_COOKIE['MyValue']);
?>
```

Note that cookies MUST be set before the  tag is called.

If cookies don't work either, then it's probably a problem with your php.ini
Can you post your php.ini if cookies don't work?

Hope this helps!

Comment: I could have been mistaken, but I don't expicitly set cookies in my code.  I just set the session variables with the users information.  Should I also be setting cookies to track the user's session?

Comment: No, don't do that.
You should use either sessions or cookies, not both.
Otherwise, it'll get confusing.