# Remember checkbox settings for 24 hours

Tags: php, html

I have a dog who needs medicine 3 times a day.

I've made a simple webpage to connect to from 2 different iPhones too keep track of who has given him medicine.

The page contains 3 check-boxes. How can I make them remember if they're checked so that if i check one, and my wife opens the page to see if I've done it, it shows.

And want the memory to be erased every day at 00:00.

What would be the simplest way to solve this task?

this is the HTML file I've got: Can anyone help me with the PHP approach?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Medisintime</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align: center">
      <h1>Medisinetime?</h1>
      <br><br>
      <form action="remember.php" method="post">
        <table style="border: 0; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left">
            <td>Amaroq Morning:</td>
            <td><input name="am" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Amaroq Midday:</td>
            <td><input name="nm" type="checkbox"></td>
            <td>Amaroq Evening:</td>
            <td><input name="ak" type="checkbox"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Register!">
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to just use something like Google Calendar? Or are you using this as a learning exercise as well as to help keep track of medicine?

Comment: You need a persistent way to keep track of the dates. You need some kind of storage, either a local API or a database.

Comment: Try: [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is a software library that implements a self-contained, serverless, zero-configuration, transactional SQL database engine. SQLite is the most widely deployed SQL database engine in the world. The source code for SQLite is in the public domain.

Comment: It's a learning exercise as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a form or DB - why not just write the current time/date to a text file every time you medicate. When the page loads - open and echo out the contents of the file so whoever is curious can see a record of medication.

PHP can do this pretty easily.

Comment: I like this approach. Not only this, but if they want the auto-clearing at midnight system, they could use JSON (or something similar), and compare the current server date to the latest data entry's date in the file. I'd consider a database overkill for this.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer is a MySQL database, but you can also do it with simple files, like a txt file or something. If you have 3 checkboxes, you need 3 files. If you use PHP, put these few lines before your html code.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['am'])) {
    file_put_contents('1.txt','');
}
if(isset($_POST['nm'])) {
    file_put_contents('2.txt','');
}
if(isset($_POST['nk'])) {
    file_put_contents('3.txt','');
}

$checked=array(false,false,false);
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++) {
    if(file_exists("$i.txt")) {
        if(date('Y-m-d',filemtime("$i.txt"))!=date('Y-m-d')) {
            file_delete("$i.txt");
        }
        else {
            $checked[$i-1]=true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can check for the $checked array's values later in the html like:

```
    <td>Amaroq Morning:</td>
        <td><input name="am" type="checkbox" <?php if($checked[0]) { echo 'checked'; } ?>></td>
```

Not the cleanest, but a working solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to suggest (in technical point of view) .

```
1. You have created a form right.

2. Now create a simple table contain id,medicine_1,medicine_2,medicine_3

3. After checking any checkbox save form and load the same page.

4. next time when page loads check if any medicine_1 ==1 OR medicine_2==1 OR medicine_3==1

5.If any value is checked then accordingly checked that checkbox.

6. So this way you can know which medicine is provided.

7. And finally check if time is 00:00 then remove that row.
```

Thats it.

But personally I will suggest use reminder kind of stuff which contain account and you and your spouse can use the same account and made changes accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

#### Cookies and PHP sessions.

It could work. Something like:

If session doesn't exist, create a new session with the value of the current date and desired time.

If the session does exist, compare the time of the session value and the current time. If it's not time yet, leave the check boxes as it is. Else, clear the check box.

Seems pretty simple. Then you can add the check box logic inside those two ifs.

[Make sure your sessions are able to last for 24 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430548/how-to-make-user-session-go-on-for-24-hours). That way they're automatically cleared if it's been more than 24 hours.

Or

## mysqlite

Keeps you from using a whole database and it's basically the same as writing to a file, but better :)

Comment: @Thomas I just reread your question and noticed your wife needs it too. I thought it was for your own use, my apologies.

Comment: @Thomas I added mysqlite to my answer, seems like your best bet besides the other options suggested here